# How can I count documents by specific date range

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have switched sql to mongodb recently and I ran into an issue.

Search schema:

```
new mongoose.Schema({
content: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
created_at: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
})
```

Some docs:

```
_id:5e077923f08564374cea9f55
content:"ds"
created_at:2019-12-28T15:47:47.318+00:00

_id:5e077924f08564374cea9f56
content:"ds"
created_at:2019-12-28T15:47:48.545+00:00

_id:5e07792bf08564374cea9f57
content:"d"
created_at:2019-12-28T15:47:55.585+00:00
```

---

How can I count search IN A DAY / WEEK / MONTH.

I have an idea, try to convert date to int. But I don't know how to do it.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use $year, $month to group your date field by year, month and then calculate count for this group. One sample query would look like this -

```
db.col.aggregate([  
    {
        $group: {
                "_id": {
                    "year" : {
                        $year : "$createdDate"
                    },
                    "month" : {
                        $month : "$createdDate"
                    }
                },
                "count": {
                    $sum: 1
                }   
            }
    }    
])
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I count documents by specific date range

You can specify a range of dates, `start` and `end` (and this range can include any number of days: one day, 7 days, 30 days, etc.) and get a *count* for that.

```
var start = ISODate("2019-12-25T09:00:00.000+00:00")
var end = ISODate("2019-12-30T17:00:00.000+00:00")

db.dates.aggregate( [
  { 
      $match: { 
          $and: [ { created_at: { $gte: start } }, 
                  { created_at: { $lte: end } } 
                ] 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $group: { 
          _id: null, 
          count: { $sum: 1 } 
      } 
  }
] )
```

The query can *also* be written as a single `$group` stage:

```
{ 
  $group: { 
      _id: null, 
      count: { 
          $sum: {
               $cond: [ 
                   { $and: [ 
                         { $gte: [ "$created_at", start ] }, 
                         { $lte: [ "$created_at", end ] } 
                    ] }, 
                    1, 
                    0
               ]
          } 
      } 
  } 
}
```